# Implementing interactive SSH login in mobile app using Dart & Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

How I can create a UI in dart which revert sshSession input and output whenever required? we have similar implementation in C#. But I'm looking for more into sshlogin through mobile application.

I have tried creating two box one for input and other for output and it is working for non-interactive shell.